# SignalR .Net client - how to invoke synchronously and asynchronously

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I'm learning SignalR using the .Net client (not javascript), and was hoping for some clarification on how to invoke hub proxy methods in a synchronous or asynchronous manner.

**Method with no return value**

So far I've been doing something like this:-

```
myHubProxy.Invoke("DoSomething");
```

I've found this to be asynchronous, which is fine as it's effectively "fire-and-forget" and doesn't need to wait for a return value. A couple of questions though:-

1. Are there any implications with wrapping the Invoke in a try..catch block, particularly with it being asynchronous? I might want to know if the call failed.
2. Are there any scenarios where you would want to call a method that doesn't return a value *synchronously*? I've seen the .Wait() method mentioned, but I can't think why you would want to do this.

**Method *with* return value**

So far I've been using the `Result` property, e.g.:-

```
var returnValue = myHubProxy.Invoke<string>("DoSomething").Result;
Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
```

I'm assuming this works *synchronously* - after all, it couldn't proceed to the next line until a result had been returned. But how do I invoke such a method asynchronously? Is it possible to specify a callback method, or should I really be using async/await these days (something I confess to still not learning about)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write asynchronous code, then you should use `async`/`await`. [I have an intro on my blog with a number of followup resources at the end.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

When you start an asynchronous operation (e.g., `Invoke`), then you get a task back. The `Task` type is used for asynchronous operations without a return value, and `Task<T>` is used for asynchronous operations with a return value. These task types can indicate to your code when the operation completes and whether it completed successfully or with error.

Although you *can* use `Task.Wait` and `Task<T>.Result`, I don't recommend them. For one, they wrap any exceptions in an `AggregateException`, which make your error handling code more cumbersome. It's far easier to use `await`, which does not do this wrapping. Similarly, you can register a callback using `ContinueWith`, but I don't recommend it; you need to understand a lot about task schedulers and whatnot to use it correctly. It's far easier to use `await`, which does the (most likely) correct thing by default.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now: I would write a method (marked `async`) that contains the call to Invoke (marked `await`) followed by the code that does something with the return value. I then call this method, which will return as soon as it calls Invoke(), allowing the calling code to carry on with other things. The remaining code in the method will only be run after Invoke() completes - the equivalent of a callback delegate. (I'm not convinced that async/await results in code that is more readable than the old callback delegate approach, but that's just my opinion!)

Answer (score 0):

The `.Result` property returns a async Task, so the server requests is still performed async.
There is not reason to hold up a thread for the duration of the call thats why you use async.

If you fire the call on the GUI thread its even more important todo it async because otherwise the GUI will not respond while the call is done

1) Yuo need to use the await keyword if you want try catch blocks to actually catch server faults. Like

```
try
{
    var foo = await proxy.Invoke<string>("Bar");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //act on error
}
```

2) I think you ment to ask if its any reason to call it async? And yes like I said, you do not want to block any threads while the request is being made

Comment: I'm still unclear on how I would call `Invoke` asynchronously then let the thread get on with other things while the server method runs. When the call completes I want to do something with the return value, a bit like a callback delegate (a common approach before async/await were introduced). I'm not sure what the equivalent code would be using async/await.